# How to pass a closure as action to tap gesture added to a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want a on click function on a UIView, but I don't know how can I pass in that closure in the first picture in the function:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are no "clicks" in iOS; there are "taps".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*First of all: I would highly recommend to add code snippets instead of screenshot in your question(s).*

You need to pass a `Selector` for the action parameter in `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of `() -> ()` closure:

```
extension UIView {
    func onClick(target: Any, _ selector: Selector) {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: selector)
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that at this point you have to set the appropriate `target` for the `tap` instance, which means it is *not* `self` in the `UIView` extension (as implemented in your code); Instead, you have to pass it as an argument to the `onClick` method.

**Usage:**

In your ViewController:

```
likesImg.onClick(target: self, #selector(likesImgClicked))

@objc private func likesImgClicked() {
    print(#function)
}
```

When saying `likesImg.onClick(target: self`: `self` here means the ViewController itself, not the `UIView` extension, that's the correct target because `likesImgClicked` implemented in the ViewController but not in the `UIView` extension.

---

### UPDATE:

**If you are insist to the approach of passing a closure, you could follow this solution:**

Implement your UIView extension as:

```
extension UIView {
    private struct OnClickHolder {
        static var _closure:()->() = {}
    }

    private var onClickClosure: () -> () {
        get { return OnClickHolder._closure }
        set { OnClickHolder._closure = newValue }
    }


    func onClick(target: Any, _ selector: Selector) {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector)
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func onClick(closure: @escaping ()->()) {
        self.onClickClosure = closure

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onClickAction))
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc private func onClickAction() {
        onClickClosure()
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

In your ViewController:

```
likesImg.onClick {
    print("Hello!!")
}
```

**IMPORTANT:**

Thanks to [@Josh Caswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell) for the following note:

> Note that the private struct gets you one storage location *for the
>   entire program*. If you try to set a handler on more than one view,
>   the second will overwrite the first.

Comment: can´t i use a closure somehow ? its just like always just the uitapgesture decleration isn´t there. I mean how does the other functions from apple work? like animation blocks etc.

Comment: Thank you :) I'll try it but what is newValue in the onClickClosure? Where is defined?

Comment: Its working when printing things, but when i use Firestore Database it doesn´t work properly. So i need to use the old style again :(

Comment: `newValue` is related to the set of the computed property. Choose the better approach for your case...

Comment: Note that the private struct gets you one storage location *for the entire program*. If you try to set a handler on more than one view, the second will overwrite the first.

Comment: and how can that be fixed?

Comment: it's useless if you can only use it once. check my solution.

Comment: It really helps me!

Answer (score 5):

I just reinvented the swift click listener android style, based on some answers. It's very simple to use:

```
yourView.setClickListener {
    // do some actions here!
}
```

Add this to your extensions file:

```
final class ClickListener: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    private var action: () -> Void

    init(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
        super.init(target: nil, action: nil)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(execute))
    }

    @objc private func execute() {
        action()
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func setClickListener(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let click = ClickListener(action)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(click)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xcode 11.7 and Swift 5.2

I have created a common Button action. Please refer below code

```
    import UIKit


    func customBarButton(_ target: Any, selector: Selector, controlEvent: UIControl.Event, buttonImage: String) -> UIBarButtonItem{
        let customButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        customButton.setImage(UIImage(named: buttonImage), for: .normal)
        customButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
        customButton.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: controlEvent)
        let filterItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButton)

        return filterItem
    }
```

I have used the above code in my viewcontroller files.

initialize in viewdidload.

```
    let searchItem = customBarButton(self, selector: #selector(didTapSearchButton(_:)), controlEvent: .touchUpInside, buttonImage: "search")
    
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [searchItem]
```

the function called on Touch of button:

```
@objc func didTapSearchButton(_ sender: Any){
 //enter code here
}
```